# reading from file in java

Tags: java, file-io

I am reading from a file using this code:

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("example.txt"));


      String line;
 while((line = in.readLine()) != null)
{
         String k = line;
        System.out.println(k);
 }
in.close();
```

This works perfectly fine.. However my text file contains "1. Hello 2. Bye 3. Seeya".. How can i modify my code so that "1. Hello" stores in a variable.. "2. Bye" stores in a different variable.. and so on
 Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can't create variables on the fly. Use an array.

Comment: How to do it totally depends on your file format. You need to specify how is the text in your file formatted. Is it confirm that there is always a number? Is it always that the content of each variable will start with a number? Will there be empty lines in the file?

Comment: Is text `1. Hello 2. Bye 3. Seeya` in one line or each part is in separate line?

Comment: they are in separate lines

Comment: Then use List implementation like ArrayList. It is similar to array, but with this difference that it can be *resized* so you can add new elements without fear that you will be out of bound.

Answer (score 1):

If it's one line, you can use the following:

```
s.split("(?<=\\w)\\s"));
```

Since [`split`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-) accepts a regex, you can split according to space that was preceded by a character.

Quick example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "1. Hello 2. Bye 3. Seeya";
    System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(s.split("(?<=\\w)\\s")));
}
```

Output:

```
[1. Hello, 2. Bye, 3. Seeya]
```

If you're referring multiple lines, you can simply loop on the lines and add each one to an `ArrayList`.

<sup>If your input can contain one or more strings on each number bullet, you should use `\\s(?=\\d+[.])` which is a space followed by number and a dot - thanks @pshemo</sup>

Comment: In case data could be `1. hello world 2. Bye bye 3. Seeya` I would prefer `\\s(?=\\d+[.])` to avoid splitting between `hello world` for instance.

Comment: Based on [OP comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28794515/reading-from-file-in-java#comment45863815_28794515) it looks like all these values are in fact in separate lines, so we don't need to split them but simply store them somewhere like in List.

Answer (score 0):

**This is how you can do it..**

Since the data is in separate lines, it is very straight forward. You can simply use an `arrayList` to receive the data.

ArrayList can "grow" and "shrink" as needed. Unlike arrays which has fixed size.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException
 {
      List<String> record = new ArrayList<String>();     //Use arraylist to store data
      Scanner fScn = new Scanner(new File(“Data.txt”));
      String data;

      while( fScn.hasNextLine() ){
           data = fScn.nextLine();
           record.add(data);   //Add line of text to the array list
      }
      fScn.close();
 }
```

To retrieve your records from your arraylist, you can simply use a for-loop or for-each loop.

```
for(int x=0; x<record.size(); x++)
    System.out.println(record.get(x));  

//Get specific record with .get(x) where x is the element id starting from 0. 
//0 means the first element in your arraylist.
```